# DB2 Trigger Error : An unexpected token "OR INSERT" was found following SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.68.61

Tags: trigger, db2

I am getting an error while executing the following queries. As per the DB2 documentation, we can have both update and insert event in the same trigger, but when I am trying to do so I am getting an error.

```
CREATE TABLE NULL_LOOKUP (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE PARENT (
    PARENT_ID INT NOT NULL,
    PARENT_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE CHILD_ONE (
    CHILD_ONE_ID INT NOT NULL,
    CHILD_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PARENT_ID INT
);

--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RESET_NULL_TRIGGER 
BEFORE UPDATE OF PARENT_ID OR INSERT ON CHILD_ONE 
REFERENCING NEW AS N 
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (N.PARENT_ID IS NULL) 
    BEGIN ATOMIC
    SET N.PARENT_ID = (SELECT ID FROM NULL_LOOKUP WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PARENT');
    END
@ 
--#SET TERMINATOR ;
```

Comment: What DB2 version? Make sure you reference documentation for the actual version you're using.

Comment: It's on DB2 Express-C 10.5

Comment: Try `BEGIN` in place of `BEGIN ATOMIC`.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you very much.
How come `BEGIN` works but not `BEGIN ATOMIC` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `BEGIN ATOMIC` with just `BEGIN` in the trigger body.

`BEGIN ATOMIC` indicates an *inlined* compound SQL statement, BEGIN -- a *compiled* compound statement. [Documentation states](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000931.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-7-105&lang=en):

> If multiple events are specified, the triggered action must be a compound SQL (**compiled**) statement.